# Finding Directories that Has Specific Files Init

Tags: python-3.x

I am tryin to find the specific files in the folder directory which is complicated.
Let me show the directories

[This is the Final File Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9okRF.png)

[This is the First Folder Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dggSs.png)

[This is the Second Folder Directory1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1ctr.png)

[This is the Second Folder Directory2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uN7kc.png)

I need to find each and every folders that has the "_Caminfo.dat" and "running.csv" both files init or not

This is the codes I tried

```
import glob

FP= "D:\python_workspace-shim\copied_data/*"      ## FP = File Path
FL = glob.glob(FP)

FN = ["_Caminfo.dat", "running.csv"]              ## the specific files I want to find

for i in range(0, len(FL)):
    
    FP2 = FP2 = glob.glob(FL[i] + "/*")
    
    for j in range(0, len(FN)):
        
        FN2 = FN[j]
        
        for k in range(0, len(FP2)):
            
            adr = FP2[k] + '/0000/02_output/' + FP2[k][37:39] + FP2[k][40:42] + '0000/' + FN2     ## adr = Address
            FN3 = glob.glob(adr)
            
            for len(FN2) in adr:
                if len(FN2) not in adr:
                
                    print(FN3)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please clarify what your question is.  Do note that in Windows, you need to escape ```\```.  i.e. change ```\``` to ```\\```.  So ```"D:\\python_workspace-shim\\copied_data\\*" ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code will output all folder paths that contains one of those 2 files, the list is sorted to make reading the output easier.

```py
from glob import glob

path = "Parent folder path"

list_files = glob(path + "\\**\\_CamInfo.dat", recursive = True) + glob(path + "\\**\\running.csv", recursive = True)

print(*sorted(list_files), sep="\n")
```